# Multiple Homestead Boxes

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm trying to install multiple of the same homestead box.  Each one for a different project, totally isolated from each other.  None of them will be run concurrently, only one at a time.

But when I try to run `vagrant up`, it tells me that a box with the name 'homestead-7' already exists.  How can I rename it?

I don't see the name anywhere in the vagrantfile in the project directory, nor any 'boxes' folder in either the project .vagrant directory or my home .vagrant directory.  `vagrant global-status` tells me that there is 1 homestead-7 box already for the project that is already in progress.

Comment: I'm curious, why don't you just use 1 homestead?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add *"name"* property under your *"Homestead.yaml"* file, for example:
**name: my-new-homestead**
and make sure that your *authorize*, *keys* and *folders* are pointing to the correct path.

Answer (score 2):

To use Homestead in a per project basis, you need to add it as a dependency in each one of your projects:

```
composer require laravel/homestead --dev
```

Use `php vendor/bin/homestead make` to generate the `Vagrantfile` and `Homestead.yaml` files. Then you can simply run `vagrant up` from your project.

See more on the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#per-project-installation).

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev what is your question?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. This part is absolutely not clear to me. What does it mean - homestead per project. Does it mean that would me a separate virtual machine per project? Separate DBMS? How would I "vagrant up" these machines? From the project directory?

Comment: Yes, it means having a separate VM per project, each one with it's own DB. To start up each VM, you would need to `vagrant up` from inside your project directory.

Comment: Thank you very-very much, so in this case the `composer require` will be the replacement for the `git clone`? And I still need to call `init` for every project? And manually set `ip` and `name` in every Homestead.yaml?

Comment: Yes, use `composer` to install Homesteand on your project and then the `make` command to generate the `Homestead.yaml` file. It's all detailed in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything is clear for me and the documentation does make sense. I wanted to ask these questions for 5 years now. And you finally gave me all the answers. Thank you.